# Fragments RecyclerView Databinding Kotlin - Unresolved reference variable name

Tags: android, kotlin, android-fragments, android-recyclerview, data-binding

I was trying `DataBinding` on a Small Project which has some fragments and one of the fragments hosts a `RecyclerView`.
The child item has a `DataBinding`which I am unable to access in the `RecyclerView` Adapter.
How to solve this?
[image]

ShopFragment.KT

```
class ShopFragment : Fragment(),ShopItemsAdapter.ShopInterface {
  lateinit  var fragmentShopBinding: FragmentShopBinding;
    lateinit var shopItemsAdapter: ShopItemsAdapter ;
    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        fragmentShopBinding= FragmentShopBinding.inflate(inflater,container,false)

        return  fragmentShopBinding.root;

    }

    override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        shopItemsAdapter = ShopItemsAdapter();
        fragmentShopBinding.shopRV.adapter=shopItemsAdapter;
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)
    }

    override fun addItem(productModel: ProductModel) {
        TODO("Not yet implemented")
    }

    override fun onItemClick(productModel: ProductModel) {
        TODO("Not yet implemented")
    }
}
```

FragmentShop.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    tools:context=".views.ShopFragment">

    <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/shopRV"
        app:layoutManager="androidx.recyclerview.widget.GridLayoutManager"
        app:spanCount="2"
        tools:listitem="@layout/shop_item"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />
</FrameLayout>
```

shopItem.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

    <data>
    <variable
        name="productModel"
        type="com.example.mvvm_shopping_cart.models.ProductModel" />
    </data>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">


        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/productIV"
            android:layout_width="100dp"
            android:layout_height="100dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/iphone" />

        <TextView
            style="@style/TextAppearance.MaterialComponents.Body1"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:id="@+id/textView"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@{productModel.name}" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:id="@+id/priceTV"
            style="@style/TextAppearance.MaterialComponents.Caption"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@{productModel.price.toString()}" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:id="@+id/availableTV"
            style="@style/TextAppearance.MaterialComponents.Caption"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@{productModel.available? `Available` : `Out of stock`}" />

        <Button
            android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.MaterialComponents.Caption"
            style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.Button.TextButton"
            android:id="@+id/AddBtn"
            android:enabled="@{productModel.available}"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Add to cart" />
    </LinearLayout>
</layout>
```

ProductModel.kt

```
class ProductModel(var id : Number,var  name : String,var  imageUrl : String, var price : Number, var isAvailable : Boolean) {
    override fun toString(): String {
        return super.toString()
    }

    override fun equals(other: Any?): Boolean {
        return super.equals(other)
    }

    class ShopItemCallBack : DiffUtil.ItemCallback<ProductModel>() {
        override fun areItemsTheSame(oldItem: ProductModel, newItem: ProductModel): Boolean {
            return newItem.id == oldItem.id;
        }

        override fun areContentsTheSame(oldItem: ProductModel, newItem: ProductModel): Boolean {
            return newItem == oldItem;
        }

    }

}
```

ShopItemAdapter.kt

```
class ProductModel(var id : Number,var  name : String,var  imageUrl : String, var price : Number, var isAvailable : Boolean) {
    override fun toString(): String {
        return super.toString()
    }

    override fun equals(other: Any?): Boolean {
        return super.equals(other)
    }

    class ShopItemCallBack : DiffUtil.ItemCallback<ProductModel>() {
        override fun areItemsTheSame(oldItem: ProductModel, newItem: ProductModel): Boolean {
            return newItem.id == oldItem.id;
        }

        override fun areContentsTheSame(oldItem: ProductModel, newItem: ProductModel): Boolean {
            return newItem == oldItem;
        }

    }

}
```

I am unable to find the issue, please help.

Answer (score 0):

> [image]

#### Problem:

You are using the wrong generated binding class; as the `FragmentShopBinding` is the generated class of the `fragment_shop.xml` which is a fragment layout that contains the `RecyclerView` ifselft not `RecyclerView` item layout. And therefore it didn't resolve the `product` view.

#### Solution:

To fix this you need to replace the `FragmentShopBinding` with the generated class associated to the row item layout where it is `shopItem.xml`, and the generated class would be `ShopItemBinding`:

```
class ShopViewHolder(var itemView: ShopItemBinding): RecyclerView.ViewHolder(itemView.root) {

    //......
}
```